# clojure sum of all the primes under 2000000

Tags: optimization, clojure, functional-programming, primes

It's a Project Euler problem .

I learned from [Fastest way to list all primes below N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n-in-python)
and implemented a clojure :

```
(defn get-primes [n]
  (loop [numbers (set (range 2 n))
         primes []]
    (let [item (first numbers)]
      (cond 
        (empty? numbers)
        primes
        :else
        (recur (clojure.set/difference numbers (set (range item n item)))
               (conj primes item))))))
```

used like follows:

```
(reduce + (get-primes 2000000))
```

but It is so slow..

I am wondering why, Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Incidentally, that `cond` only has two branches, so you may want to replace it with an `if`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This algorithm is not even correct: at each iteration except the final one it adds the value of `(first numbers)` at that point to `primes`, but there is no guarantee that it will in fact be a prime, since the set data structure in use is unordered. (This is also true of the Python original, as mentioned by its author in an edit to the question you link to.) So, you'd first need to fix it by changing `(set (range ...))` to `(into (sorted-set) (range ...))`.

Even then, this is simply not a great algorithm for finding primes. To do better, you may want to write an imperative implementation of the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) using a Java array and `loop` / `recur`, or maybe a functional SoE-like algorithm such as those described in Melissa E. O'Neill's beautiful paper [The Genuine Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf).

Comment: Not adding the code for any particular solution so as to avoid spoiling the Project Euler exercise.